# Як перекласти з англійської "bench press"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Як перекласти з англійської "bench press"? Зустрічав такі українські переклади: відтискання лежачи, тиснення лежачи вивага лежачи. Також знаю що часто використовуєтсья калька з російської "Жим лежачи", але сам іменник "жим" - російський, тому цей варіант не підходить.

Comment: Родич запитанє: [Коротша назва вправи _згинання та розгинання рук в упорі лежачи_](/q/1147/585)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Олександр Пономарів [пише](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2016/01/160118_ponomariv_blog80_ko):

> *Французский жим* словники подають як *французький жим*. Мені це не подобається, тому я запропонував би *французький витиск*.

Але при цьому на запитання «Станіслав Свидлов цікавиться, якому варіянтові віддати перевагу в назві фізичної вправи, яка англійською буде bench press: відтискання лежачи, тиснення лежачи чи вивага лежачи?» він раніше [відповів](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/09/150903_ponomariv_blog65_ko):

> Оскільки, виконуючи цю вправу, людина лежить на лавці й виважує штангу, то, мабуть, краще казати *вивага штанги*.

Хоча я не впевнений, що це різні вправи.

Answer (score 5):

Сайт словотвір пропонує окрім вищезгаданих Вами слів такі відповідники до слова *жим*:

> витиск, підйом, відтиск.

Слово [відтиск](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidtysk) в українській мові вживається в значенні **[відбиток](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidbytok)**, тому для даного перекладу не підходить. 
На мою думку **вивага лежачи** найкраще підходить як переклад "bench press".

Хоча в СУМі ми знаходимо слово [жим](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhym).